# Setting background color of child element in SASS depending on width of parent element (SASS)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I am new to SASS. Actually, I want to set background of a span inside a class (.someClass) as 'yellow' or 'orange' based on the width of (.someClass div element). I could easily do same in jQuery, but here I have to do in React so trying achieve by `SASS`. Can someone help me out with correct syntax. I heard can use variables and conditionals in SASS so trying it out.

```
@if ('.someClass').width < 90px {
 & > span {background:yellow;}
}
else {
 & > span {background:orange;}
}
```

Please, someone help me out!

Comment: I am new to SASS and this seemed a valid question! :/ ... and I heard can do these items using variables and if-else functions in SASS. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can try and do this using mixins:

```
$width:auto;
@mixin background($width) {

  @if $width <= '90px' {
    background:red;
  } @else {
    background:blue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could detect the width of the viewport and set styles accordingly with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

To change the styles of one element based on the size of another will require use of JavaScript. Sass variables, functions, and conditionals don't work in the way you are describing as they are calculated at compile time and output to regular CSS.